# if a /p input contains a certain word(s) within it

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement

hope you guys had a great Thanksgiving!

Anyways, I've been looking around for an answer for this, but I can't seem to find one that I need.

So basically my batch file has an input in which you write a sentence. The sentence will take you to :correct as long as it has the words "Mommy Chan" in it.

```
@echo off
:start
set /p test=Write a sentene with the word Mommy Chan in it: 

if "%test%"=="Mommy Chan" goto correct
if "%test%" NEQ "Mommy Chan" goto incorrect

:correct
cls
echo %test%
echo you did it
pause
goto start

:incorrect
cls
echo %test%
echo you didn't follow directions
pause
goto start
```

Now, this seems to work and brings you to :correct if the user puts in the words "Mommy Chan" for the input, and nothing else. However, say the user puts in "Not Mommy Chan" it doesn't seem to recognize the fact that the word "Mommy Chan" is included, and it takes you to :incorrect

Obviously I don't want that.

**For clarification, I want it so that if you input any sentence that has the word "Mommy Chan" in it, for example: "One day Mommy Chan went shopping" it should bring you to :correct.** However, it only does this if the user puts in ONLY "Mommy Chan" Otherwise it just takes you to :incorrect

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way:

```
@echo off
:start
set /p test=Write a sentene with the word Mommy Chan in it: 
::replaces "Mommy Chan" in %test% to see if it was changed
if "%test:Mommy Chan=%" equ "%test%" goto incorrect
if "%test:Mommy Chan=%" neq "%test%"  goto correct
exit /b 0

:correct

echo correct

exit /b 0


:incorrect

echo incorrect

exit /b 0
```

Another one (probably slower because it calls find.exe):

```
@echo off
:start
set /p test=Write a sentene with the word Mommy Chan in it: 

echo %test%|find "Mommy Chan"  >nul 2>nul && (
  goto :correct
  color
)||(
   goto incorrect
)
exit /b 0

:correct

echo correct

exit /b 0


:incorrect

echo incorrect

exit /b 0
```

for case insensitive check - both `IF` and `FIND` use `/I` switch.

Comment: Quick question, what exactly did adding the phrase needed and the colon do? (if "%test:Mommy Chan=%")

Comment: @MikeSteele - `%test:Mommy Chan=%` removes all instances of `Mommy Chan` from the contents of `%test%`. This way, if the substring is present, the two strings will be different.